# House robber in Python Explanation

Tags: python

I was browsing solutions on leetcode and found this for HouseRobber 1:

```
    last, now = 0, 0
    for i in nums:
        last, now = now, max(last + i, now)
    return now
```

I'm kind of confused on how the code itself executes with the max value. It's a bit ambiguous to me since I'm still fairly new to python and coming from C++, I wrote something like this:

```
lastNum = 0 #last number we took in
    lastSpot = 0 #last spot we took the number from (index placeholder)
    totalSum = 0 #max amount we can take from the houses
    for i, element in enumerate(nums):
        if element > lastNum: #if our element is bigger than our last number, we check...
            if lastSpot != i - 1: #if our last spot was more than a space away AND our element is bigger, we take our index number.
                if lastNum + nums[lastSpot] < lastNum + nums[i]:
                    lastNum = element
                    totalSum += element
                    lastSpot = i #update our last spot
            elif lastSpot == i - 1: #if our last spot is next to our current spot, we gotta' swap a few values now.
                totalSum -= lastNum #we remove the last value we added since we found a bigger spot
                totalSum += element
                lastSpot = i
                lastNum = element
        elif i == lastSpot + 2: #if we are more than one spot away from our last spot, we take the number anyway and add it.
            lastNum = element
            totalSum += element
        elif element < lastNum:
            if lastNum + nums[lastSpot] < lastNum + nums[i]:
                lastNum = element
                totalSum += element
                totalSum += nums[i - 2]
                lastSpot = i        
        else:   
            lastNum = element

    return totalSum
```

I understand that we need to validate the values against each other and if we pass a value, we check to see if it's bigger than our last held value plus our current, then decide to skip or take depending on if it's a spot next to our currently chosen value. But how does that execute within the small bit of python code? I know how the max function takes 2 values and returns the larger of two - but am I missing something? Shouldn't this also be returning values next to the same value? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is your main question about how `last, now = now, max(last + i, now)` works? What do you mean by "values next to the same value?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code on each for iteration doing like below:

```
temp = last
last = now
now = max(temp + i, now)
```

so this code in c++ actually looks like:

```
last = 0;
now = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    temp = last;
    last = now;
    now = max(temp + nums[i], now);
}
```

Comment: Your first block is right, but I think you accidentally put `now = max(last + i, now)` instead of `now = max(temp + i, now)` in your loop. And the `i` in there should be `num[i]`, since it's `for i in nums`. Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: @BakhromRakhmonov Okay, so essentially we are iterating through, then using the max to check the max between our current and our value + 1 in index terms? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is simple dp problem. but not value + 1, lastvalue+current house money